# What causes extra swaps?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

As far as I can tell, I seem to get an "extra swap" when I make a particularly good move. However, sometimes it seems like I get an "extra swap" for matching a couple of color groups, and other times it seems like I clear many groups and don't get an "extra swap". What exactly do I have to do to qualify?

Additionally, is it possible to chain multiple extra swaps in a single turn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a combination of 5 or more gems of the same colour you will get an extra swap.

Swapping 3 green **and** 3 red in a single move will **not** get you an extra swap.

As for the chaining: I have asked support whether it is possible, but I believe it will be. Although it will be hard to get a chain since it requires 5 or more gems from the same colour.

Comment: It is definitely possible to get "1 Extra Swap", then during that extra swap earn another Extra Swap. However if one cascade happens to match 5 gems twice, you still only earn one extra swap.

Comment: And it is possible to get an extra swap even though you manually matched 3, if the resulting cascade matches 3 more of the same color.